# Rails plugin for generating dynamic / ajax crud interfaces compatible with Rails 3 beta?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

Anyone know of some good gems or plugins to create dynamic / ajax crud interfaces for Rails 3 projects? I know active scaffold was popular before and it's been awhile since I have used it / any other gems similar to this (I usually just write it myself).

I like the direction that the formtastic gem (http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) is headed and wonder what else people are combining with it.

Also I like the [generators](http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators)  approach that Ryan Bates uses and he appears to be making updates for Rails 3.

Anything else I am missing here? (I am also open to gems not compatible with Rails 3 too I guess, I can always make a contribution and try to help them get to the next phase. ;))

Comment: One hyperlink only for new users. If you think stackoverflow.com is lame, why are you asking here ?

Comment: One hyperlink for new users is a measure to stop spammers from posting a whole bunch of links. Any feature that slows down spammers is a good feature, not a lame one.

Comment: Ok guess I'll keep posting and get the points up. And correction retro I don't think stackoverflow is lame, more curious as to the their statistics on spam decrease with said feature. ;)

Comment: @mrh: they get a significant amount of spam, but it gets shut down quickly. One link isn't all *that* bad; most questioners don't need any, regardless of rep. And don't worry, help out and post good answers and that rep will be up so quick you'll wonder why you ever bothered to say "lame" in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [admin_data](http://github.com/neerajdotname/admin_data) for the basic CRUD backend of a site running Rails 3 beta in production. I tried several others and had compatibility issues with Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fork of active scaffold compatible with rails3:
http://vhochstein.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/setupactivescaffoldrails3/
More info:
http://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold
http://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold/wiki
http://groups.google.com/group/activescaffold/browse_thread/thread/b0447f2c3c655a45/f2f3687e7d954590

I'll take on the occasion to mention some of my personal toughts on AS vis-a-vis of Rail3:

- AS needs to decouple on AR and work with ActiveModel instead
- it needs to offer some sort of plug-able column introspection API, so it can work with other ORMs like Mongoid
- the AS configuration needs to be per request (instance level) not global (thread safety, simpler to hack), or global with stateless per-request overrides (hope it makes sense), the first approach is a lot better

maybe write a thingy from scratch ...

PS. AS is one of the best pieces of software i have used, many people do not get to understand it's power because of the pretty steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can DRY up your crud controllers with the inherited_resources gem: http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources

Answer (score 0):

[rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) was written from the ground-up for Rails 3 -- I use it in basically every project